# Is it safe to use only Data and System scoped units to build mutiplatform

Tags: delphi, scope, delphi-xe, multiplatform, delphi-units

Since XE2 the Delphi units are scoped.

[Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names)

[Unit Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Names_Alphabetical_List_with_Unit_Scopes)

Is is right to say that if I use only System and Data scoped units my code will be multiplatform and compiled for both Mac and Windows targets?

and the rest of the Vcl, Winapi, and Posix references must be governed by conditional compilation platform symbols?

Comment: Well, there's your code too. You need to be sure that it's x-plat too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data` - in general, no. For example, `Data.DBXMsSQL` (SQL Server dbExpress driver) is supported on Windows only. Also `System` and `Data` "root" scopes may have `Win` subscope, supported on Windows only. For example, `Data.Win.ADODB` (dbGo) or `System.Win.Registry` (Windows registry). Beside that `System` and `Data` are crossplatform. Additionally to `Data` the `DataSnap` scope is crossplatform.

`Vcl`, `Winapi`, and `Posix` you can IFDEF. Other option is to create and use platform specific application units and IFDEF them in `uses`.